# serialize String property as nested JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need the String property of object to be serialized as nested JSON without any escaping etc. So given json:

```
{
  "regularProperty" : "Test here",
  "nestedJSON" : {
    "propertyArray" : [1,2,3],
    "propertyText" : "new Text",
    "anotherObject" : { ... }
  }
}
```

And the **nestedJSON** property must contain the text

```
{
  "propertyArray" : [1,2,3],
  "propertyText" : "new Text",
  "anotherObject" : { ... }
}
```

How is it possible for both serialization/deserialization? Any specific annnotation or data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe add the annotation [JsonRawValue](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/) on the *nestedJSON* field? I never used it before but it seems quite promising for your case.